# Magento2 product image path issue

Tags: magento2

After migrate the website from localhost to server I see that all image is 404 now and when I see the path I see that product images are path are wrong in everywhere .

Now the path is being call

> pub/media/catalog/productcache/aa0b8856d0d44b2f592207c1826506a3/9/_/9_6.jpg

Where as it need to be

> pub/media/catalog/product/cache/aa0b8856d0d44b2f592207c1826506a3/9/_/9_6.jpg

So what I understand is here is only the slash(/) is missing between product and cache.

I run all command like setup:upgrade , catalog image resize, content deploy .

But nothing solve the issue. Anyone face the same issue before ? Can you tell me how to solve it ?

Comment: No in developer mode

Comment: Those steps already done by me

Comment: it have apache installed

Comment: ok then check rewrite mode is on or not ? it must be on ,

Comment: Yes that is on because urls are working fine

Comment: But my images are comming from catalog/product/ folder then pub/static folder image will be not effect on other folder.

Comment: then remove cache folder from there and run commands again

Comment: @AsishHira sorry it was typo mistake i am trying to say is `pub/media` folder

Answer (score 3):

Delete files inside these folders from server file manager or FTP

```
var/cache
var/page_cache
var/view_preprocessed
var/generation
```

Then run following commands in sequence

```
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade

    php bin/magento setup:di:compile

    php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

    php bin/magento cache:clean

    php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production

php bin/magento cache:enable

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

I hope this should solve out your problem

Comment: I already said in my question that I did those things

Comment: try using setting production mode

Answer (score 0):

[image: Admin screen path]Wrong image cache in frontend

I solved it with update the admin settings as bellow

Admin panel > Stores > Settings > Configuration > GENERAL > Web > Url Options > Catalog media URL format